How to use flutterview in Dreamservice
I need to use my flutter application as an Android screen saver.
I suppose DreamService is the solution. I try to use a flutterView in native code to display my flutter app but it is not rendered.
in my manifest i add:
        <service android:name=".screensaver.MyService"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DREAM_SERVICE">
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
            />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.service.dreams.DreamService" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

my java code
public class MyService extends DreamService {
 private FlutterEngine flutterEngine;   

@Override
public void onAttachedToWindow() {

    super.onAttachedToWindow();
    // Activer les options de l'économiseur d'écran
    setInteractive(true);
    setFullscreen(true);

    // Lancer l'activité 
    
// Initialiser Flutter Engine
    
    flutterEngine = new FlutterEngine(this);
    flutterEngine.getDartExecutor().executeDartEntrypoint(
        DartExecutor.DartEntrypoint.createDefault()
    );
    
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    FlutterView flutterView = findViewById(R.id.flutter_view);
    
    flutterView.attachToFlutterEngine(flutterEngine);


}

@Override
public void onDreamingStarted() {
    super.onDreamingStarted();
    // Logique quand l'économiseur d'écran commence
}

@Override
public void onDreamingStopped() {
    super.onDreamingStopped();
    // Logique quand l'économiseur d'écran s'arrête
}

@Override
public void onDetachedFromWindow() {
    super.onDetachedFromWindow();
    flutterEngine.destroy();
}`

my layout :
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:orientation="vertical">

<!-- Utilisez un FlutterView pour intégrer Flutter -->
<io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterView
    android:id="@+id/flutter_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>

my flutter main code :
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:waouhscreensaver/home.dart';

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  debugPrint("start");
  runApp(const WaouhScreenSaver());
}

class WaouhScreenSaver extends StatelessWidget {
  const WaouhScreenSaver({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    debugPrint("start2");
    return MaterialApp(theme: ThemeData(scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.blue), home: const Home());
  }
}

Home code :
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({super.key});

  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          var a = "";
          setState(() {});
        },
        child: Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          height: double.infinity,
          color: Colors.yellow,
          child: const Center(
            child: Text(
              'Économiseur d\'écran',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24, color: Colors.red),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
    );
  }
}

GestureDetector work fine but widget is not displayed. If i rotate screen it appear.
